# Renaming Clojure's special forms

Tags: clojure, naming-conventions, special-form

What's the best way to rename Clojure's special forms?

For example, if I preferred defvar over def or defun over defn, what would be the best way to go about it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While I perfectly agree with [amalloy's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46355625/1062189) it may be interesting to see the quick and dirty solution. You can *forward the macro call* by taking all the arguments of the original call and constructing another macro call using the genuine Clojure version.

```
(defmacro defvar [& xs] `(def ~@xs))
(defmacro defun [& xs] `(defn ~@xs))
```

Answer (score 8):

Just use `def` and `defn` instead. You *can* define macros that forward to the underlying special forms, but it's in much better taste to just use the same primitives everyone else does.

Comment: I already see the benefits of using the existing functions. It would be great if you could give an example of forwarding using macros. Thank you!